# Custom CloudFormation Resource using a .NET6 lambda function cannot find any nuGet packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have the following issue: I'm trying to create a custom CloudFormation resource using a .NET6.0 AWS Lambda function but said lambda function cannot access its nuGet packages once deployed. This is especially annoying because a rollback takes an hour.

Everything is zipped with `dotnet Amazon.Lambda.Tools` and deployed using the serverless framework with the following commands.

```
dotnet restore
dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools --framework net6.0
dotnet lambda package --project-location ../../MyLambdaProject --configuration Release --function-architecture arm64 --framework net6.0 --output-package ../myLambdaProject.zip
sls deploy
```

Here's the project file for the Lambda Function.
[image of MyLambda.csproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsGns.png)

But after deploying it cannot find any of the NuGet packages.
[AWS error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBqCX.png)

The build script I normally use works when the lambda function isn't part of a custom resource. Which leaves me at a little bit of a loss as to what's going on. I already tried specifying the runtimeIdentifier & PlatformTarget as well as zipping by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently if I run

```
cd path/to/MyLambdaProject
dotnet restore
dotnet build -c release
dotnet publish -c release
```

and then zip the generated folder "linux-arm64" and rename and deploy that it works. Why it doesn't with the aws provided tool I have no clue.